# Why is nous repeated here?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire

> **Nous** pourrions bien **nous** amuser avec ça.

Is this a rule to use *nous* again in this situation and, if it is, why?

Comment: A related English sentence: "**We** could amuse **ourselves** with that." The first _nous_ in the French sentence corresponds to "We", and the second _nous_ corresponds to "ourselves".

Answer (score 7):

The verb here is *s'amuser*. It's pronominal, which means you have to decline the pronoun.

- Je m'amuse
- Tu t'amuses
- Il/elle/on s'amuse
- Nous nous amusons
- Vous vous amusez
- Ils/elles s'amusent

When you add the modal verb *pouvoir*, you keep the pronominal bit. *Nous nous amusons* --> *Nous pourrions nous amuser*.

Comment: You don't need to use it pronominally, but then you need to add a an object: "Nous amusons le roi", "J'amuse bébé"

Comment: And this is completely parallel to English usage with that verb.

Comment: Wait, i can say Nous pourrions bien nous regardons la série télévisée.

Comment: @Brian You can't. Maybe what you want to say is: *Nous pourrions bien (nous) regarder une série télévisée* or better *On pourrait bien se regarder une série télé*.

Comment: What about " Vous pourriez bien  vous  vous levez de bonne heure"